# Why isn't useContext updating my value when imported in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the createContext and useContext features of ReactJS to create a notification icon that displays a number of notifications increasing by 1 each second (essentially trying to figure out how to pass a state between files/components), but am unable to get the value to transfer over.

The timer appears to be working fine and the seconds variable in the timer file is definitely increasing, it's just the secs in the NavBar that isn't updating correctly.

--- App File ---

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Timer />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

---Timer File---

```
...
export const secContext = createContext()
const Timer = () => {
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        ...
        if (isActive) {
            interval = setInterval(() => {
            setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
        }, 1000);}
        ...

return (
    ...
        <secContext.Provider value={seconds}>
        <div className="time">
            {seconds}s
        </div>
        ...
        </secContext.Provider>
    ...
    );
};
```

---Navigation Bar File---

```
...
import {secContext} from './Timer'
export default function NavBar() {
  const secs = useContext(secContext)

  return (
          ...
          <Badge badgeContent={secs}>
            <NotificationsIcon />
          </Badge>
          ...
   );
}
```

I was expecting {secs} in the Navigation Bar file to update to be equal the value of the seconds value from the Timer, but instead it appears to remain null.
Here is a screenshot of the interface: https://gyazo.com/d283360091c9d4ea8d9b2785419ad665
In this case the notification icon should have a badge with the number 10.

Comment: It might be helpful to also include the code you use to initialize `secContext`.

Comment: And you are sure `isActive` is being set?

Comment: @Joe Clay good call, updated

Comment: @James yep, with const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false). I'm able to confirm that it's true. Issue seems to be that useContext is returning an empty object.

Comment: @JoshEiland I presume `NavBar` is a descendant of `secContext.Provider`? I don't see where you render it in your example.

Comment: @James I started with a create-react-app, so I return the NavBar and then the Timer within App.js and then render App in App.test.js

Comment: @JoshEiland can you show an example?

Comment: @James I added a screenshot, can add any other code that would be helpful

Comment: @Dominic it was my understanding that using a provider with the context as I've done in the timer file would allow transfer of that data to the navbar file. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context values are only accessible if they are rendered within the hierarchy i.e.

```
<secContext.Provider value={x}>
  <NavBar />
</secContext.Provider>
```

`NavBar` doesn't appear to be a descendant of your context, your context is created inside `Timer` and therefore is only accessible from descendants of that component e.g.

```
<Timer>
  <NavBar />
</Timer>
```

**Update**

As per the comments discussion, if you simply want to share data between a couple of siblings, it would probably make more sense to just move the common up to the parent (`App`) and then pass the data into the siblings as props - see [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/pedantic-jackson-ixhhy).

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's helpful. Is there an alternative way to pass info to a sibling class through a mutual parent like I've tried to do with App containing the NavBar and Timer? Maybe the best approach would be calculating the number of seconds within the app and passing that to both NavBar and Timer to display the visuals, but my goal was to take in the value from one subclass and pass it to another.

Comment: @JoshEiland controlling the state in a mutual parent is the way to go. For example, you could move the logic into a `useTimer` hook, include this in your app and then pass the value into both `NavBar` / `Timer`. I can include an example if that helps.

Comment: an example would be great. Would that require rendering the `NavBar` and `Timer` elements within the `useTimer` class, or could I pass the value from `useTimer` into `App` and provide it to the other two classes when rendering them from there? Thanks so much for all the help

Comment: @JoshEiland the second scenario. I'll throw an example in.

Comment: @JoshEiland example added

Comment: thanks, that's helpful. One last question - in my code, interactions with buttons within the timer (pausing, resetting) change the value of the time accordingly. Is it possible to pass the new value of seconds within Timer back up to App (and therefore have it be reflected in the NavBar)?

Comment: @JoshEiland of course, the example I've given is just a straightforward data out from `useTimer` but you can certainly update it to handle props going in to manipulate the value. Have a look at [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), it's a good way of handling complex state.

Comment: Perfect, I'll look more into useReducer. Really appreciate it